# puppet include and variable scope

Tags: puppet

Can someone explain to me why would this work :

```
node 'puppetagent'{
    $my_role="proxmoxnode"
    include role_proxmoxnode
}

class role_proxmoxnode {
    include sshdconf
}
```

And this won't :

```
node 'puppetagent'{
    include role_proxmoxnode
}

class role_proxmoxnode {
    $my_role="proxmoxnode"
    include sshdconf
}
```

By "Work" I mean that the sshd_config.erb file set by sshdconf module will find the $my_role="proxmoxnode" as expected. By "won't work", I mean the template complaining with "Could not find value for 'my_role'"
I use puppet 3.0.

I followed the doc in http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Infrastructure_Design_Guidelines about roles.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Puppet 3.0. unqualified variables are looked up in 4 places:

1. Local scope
2. Inherited from a base class
3. Node-level
4. Top scope

**Local** scope, by the way, would apply to variables defined **in** the class, not in classes which simply include it.

So, in your first example, we go looking:

1. Is it local? No.
2. Is it in a base class? No.
3. Is it in the node?  yes.  We stop.

In the second example...

1. Is it local? No.
2. Is it in a base class? No.
3. Is it in the node? No.
4. Is it in top scope?  No.  Fail.

Clear?

Comment: Yes, and it's also clear that I'm not using a good design for what I want. I switched to a parametrised class waiting for $role and it works as needed. Thanks